# error code 108 ccavenue

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, ccavenue

i am integrating ccavenue with my ecommerce site. in some cases, i am getting this error:
Error Code:     108
Error Description:  Checksum+mismatch.

How to rectify this one?Can anybody help me

Comment: Did you solve this problem by anychance? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.. The checksum was indeed incorrect. I was hard coding at the last instant the amount to be Rs. 10 to test the integration.. but the checksum I calculated with the actual amount. Hence the incorrect checksum! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue and that is the URL. It will work, If your Redirect URL will not have any params.

For solving this issue. You will have to encode your URL via urlencode function in PHP.

```
$url= urlencode($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your merchant key of ccavenue, it changes every time you regenerate and also check your algo for checksum calculation

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the free code provided for integrating **ccavenues** with **joomla**, in the file `ps_ccavenues_info_part.php` the amount is rounded off after calculating the checksum.

I modified the code so the amount is rounded off before calculating the checksum and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your function file provided in the CCAvenue kit with this one:

```
<?php

function getchecksum($MerchantId,$Amount,$OrderId ,$URL,$WorkingKey)
{
    $str ="$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$URL|$WorkingKey";
    $adler = 1;
    $adler = adler32($adler,$str);
    return $adler;
}

function verifychecksum($MerchantId,$OrderId,$Amount,$AuthDesc,$CheckSum,$WorkingKey)
{
    $str = "$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$AuthDesc|$WorkingKey";
    $adler = 1;
    $adler = adler32($adler,$str);

    if($adler == $CheckSum)
        return "true" ;
    else
        return "false" ;
}

function adler32($adler , $str)
{
    $BASE =  65521 ;

    $s1 = $adler & 0xffff ;
    $s2 = ($adler >> 16) & 0xffff;
    for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
    {
        $s1 = ($s1 + Ord($str[$i])) % $BASE ;
        $s2 = ($s2 + $s1) % $BASE ;
            //echo "s1 : $s1 <BR> s2 : $s2 <BR>";

    }
    return leftshift($s2 , 16) + $s1;
}

function leftshift($str , $num)
{

    $str = DecBin($str);

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < (64 - strlen($str)) ; $i++)
        $str = "0".$str ;

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) 
    {
        $str = $str."0";
        $str = substr($str , 1 ) ;
        //echo "str : $str <BR>";
    }
    return cdec($str) ;
}

function cdec($num)
{

    for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++)
    {
       $temp = $num[$n] ;
       $dec =  $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) - $n - 1);
    }

    return $dec;
}
?>
```